# Does ogr2ogr from the Docker osgeo/gdal support PDF layers?

Tags: ogr2ogr

I'm trying to use the Docker `osgeo/gdal` image to extract vector data from a GeoPDF, i.e. https://www.floridastateparks.org/sites/default/files/media/file/SFHPSP_TrailMapBike_11-27-19.pdf. It's compiled with the poppler PDF backend.

`gdalinfo -mdd layers` shows plenty of layers, but `ogr2ogr` doesn't recognize any of those layers, e.g. `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" other.shp SFHPSP_TrailMapBike_11-27-19.pdf --config OGR_PDF_READ_NON_STRUCTURED YES Layers.Bike_Trails` or `--config GDAL_PDF_LAYERS ALL`

Is there an option to get `ogr2ogr` to recognize these layers, or is something else (like a different driver or a better PDF) needed?

Comment: `ogr2ogr` is for vectors - you have a raster so you should use `gdal_transform`

Comment: @IanTurton some PDFs including the one I'm looking at are drawn with vectors. `ogr2ogr` is supposed to support that when compiled correctly.

Comment: then you need to look at what `ogrinfo` says - especially in this case `ogrinfo --formats` will tell you what is compiled in

Comment: `ogr2ogr` recognizes the PDF, and the Docker osgeo/gdal image seems to be compiled "with everything". I'm looking for additional options to export vectors.

Comment: what sort of vector file do you want to create?